# FactoryGirl Association giving 'uninitialized constant' error

Tags: factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a problem with factory girl and associations.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant User::DefaultDeviceX
```

The users factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "MyString"
    email "MyString"
    password "MyString"
    association :default_device_x, factory: :device
    association :default_device_y, factory: :device
  end
end
```

Executing FactoryGirl.create(:user) raises the mentioned error above.

So, what am i doing wrong?

User model references device:

```
  belongs_to :default_device_x
  belongs_to :default_device_y
```

Device factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :device do
  name "Device 1"
  comments "Comment"
 end
end
```

Comment: show your references for `default_device_x` and `default_device_y`

Comment: Ahhh sorry, fixed it: i forgot to set :class => 'Device' attribute in user model.